# Sed conditional removal of EOL

Tags: text-processing, sed, vi

For the following example, where we have "\" at the end, the \ and EOL character should be removed.

```
line 1\
line 2
line 3
line 4\
line 5
```

Output should be

```
line 1 line 2
line 3
line 4 line 5
```

Using vi, I can get above stuff as under: `:%s/\//n//g`

But when I do it on the terminal is not working.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that it's [a `sed` FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.25).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... that Vi substitution does not work in any Vi editor I tried it in. You probably meant `:%s/\\\n/ /g` which would work in Vim but not in Vi.

---

```
$ sed '/\\$/{N;s/\\\n/ /;}' file
line 1 line 2
line 3
line 4 line 5
```

This detects whether the current line ends with a backslash, and if it does, it appends the next line (`sed` will add a newline character between them), replaces the backslash and newline with a space character.

This will fail if two consecutive lines have backslashes at the end.  For that, use something like

```
sed ':top;/\\$/{N;s/\\\n/ /;btop;}' file
```

Here, if a line with backslash has been processed, the code jumps back to the start.

Annotated version af that last `sed` script:

```
:top;             # define label "top"
/\\$/{            # the line ends with backslash
    N;            # append next line to pattern space with embedded newline
    s/\\\n/ /;    # substitute backslash and newline with space
    btop;         # branch to "top"
}
                  # (implicit print)
```